# How to send data from parent component to child component without using *ngFor in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm actually using *ngFor to repeat a selector and I'm also sending some data to the child component Please take a look at the code below :

```
<app-piegraph *ngFor="let studentData of studentData" [studentData]="studentData"></app-piegraph>
```

Parent component :

```
studentData = {first: "harish",second: "santhu"}
```

child component :

```
export class PiegraphComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input('studentData') testObj;
constructor(){
console.log(this.testObj); //Getting undefined error message here
}
}
```

I have only one object in my studentData Hence I do not want to repeat the data, I just want to send the studentData object to my child component without using *ngFor

Is this possible???

Comment: why you don't want to use `ngFor` can you add the reason for it.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Did you even try before posting question? :D

Comment: I did add the reason for not using ngFor. That's because I have only one object in my studentData hence rather than repeating it with ngFor I just want to send it directly @Aravind

Comment: Yes, I did try but couldn't find the exact solution many pages where I searched provided examples with *ngFor @AJT_82

Comment: @Harish Okay, just as a comment, your naming convention is a bit confusing, I would suggest not to have the single element have the same name as your array, i.e `*ngFor="let studentData of studentData`. Just as a comment :)

Comment: Thanks for that, will avoid same names

Comment: `testObj` will be `undefined` in constructor, place the console.log inside `OnInit` instead. Also since the naming is a bit confusing here, if `studentData` is truly an array (tho you show that studentData looks like `studentData = {first: "harish",second: "santhu"}` ) which is not iterable. But **if** it's an array you want to do: `<app-piegraph [studentData]="studentData[0]"></app-piegraph>` but if it's an object do: `<app-piegraph  [studentData]="studentData"></app-piegraph>`

Comment: That did work!! Thank you mine was an array hence I used studentData[0] and the binding that I used in the child component worked perfectly but I still keep getting error messages in my console which says can't read the property 0 of undefined, why is that?

Comment: Is the data fetching asynchronous? Then you'd want to safeguard `null` values, for example: `<app-piegraph *ngIf="studentData.length" [studentData]="studentData[0]"></app-piegraph>` also sounds like just initializing your array as an empty array could help.

Comment: I'll check by initializing an empty array and let u know

Comment: I'm actually getting these property of undefined errors in parent as well as child component html files, but when I initialized empty array in parent component the errors in parent.html are gone, I'm still getting these error messages in child component html where I binded this data

Comment: @AJT_82 Should I initialize an empty array in child component like below : 
@Input() studentDataInChild = [];

Comment: no, in parent :)

Comment: Yeyy!! It worked now perfectly without any errors!! Thank you so much. If you can post your comment as an answer I would be happy to upvote it :)

Comment: Done! :) Glad we figured it out! Have a nice day and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `studentData` is an array, and you know for sure that it only has one object you can do:

```
<app-piegraph [studentData]="studentData[0]"></app-piegraph>
```

here we need to remember to in the parent component initialize the array, so that we do not get an `undefined` error on the array.

Also, you are trying to console log the `@Input` value in child in your constructor, at that point the `@Input` value is yet not available. This can be solved by moving the console log to `OnInit`:

```
export class PiegraphComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input('studentData') testObj;

  constructor(){ }

  ngOnInit() { 
    console.log(this.testObj);
  }
}
```